# WCF - 'normal' flow for high-perf service

Tags: .net, wcf

I realize this question may not be specific 'enough' for some people. Then again, the answers may point to some help for some people.

Here's the root of my question: I want to have a high-perf service. I'm concerned about taking too much time in any one of the service methods, either on the server or on the client. I know I'm getting notified on an IO completion port, and I don't know how long any of my methods can or should take. I'm concerned that I need to offload the incoming calls onto some kind of backgrounder Q and process the incoming methods not on the IO threads. I've seen a thousand "simple" examples of how to use WCF, and at least 100 samples of how to use WCF and not deadlock a Windows UI thread, but honestly, nothing "real life" that describes this process.

**Question**:

For super high performance WCF-Services, when the user can guarantee they know what they're doing, is it "common", in the service itself, to relay the incoming call to a background Queue, to free up the IO completion port threads, and if it is common, is it necessary and/or important, or do the IO completion ports have their own queuing mechanism under the hood and I am being unnecessarily old-school, paranoid, and causing more trouble? If, for example, a service method could take up to 10 seconds to complete (god forbid), is this okay? I know I can write an async method, but this opens up a second can of worms, described further below.

**Background**:

I'm planning on turning off any WCF locking (concurrency mode = Multiple). My communication channel is `TCP/NET` and `full duplex`. The service I'm writing is going to be a "video engine" and users can tell the server to start and stop jobs, to query it for status/state, and occasionally the server will notify the clients about metadata and frame position/etc. The video server service, in addition to being a normal WCF service, will have its own thread, and will pump video and notify the users about what's going on, occasionally.

**Concern 1:**

Suppose I have a "StopJob" method that stops a complicated video job. As the user, I want the method, when I call it on the proxy, to block until the job is actually stopped, but the underlying engine being used on the server takes a long time to stop, because of some async transforms being used that take a long time to kill. Suppose I WANT it to block and don't care about my UI. In the service, I get the Stop method, and ... then wait 10 seconds (or longer). Is this okay? If I offload it onto a background thread, I need to add a method to my callback interface, and notify the user when the stop actually happened, or I need to write the method as an async method. Both of which scare me a little bit.

**Concern 2:**

For operations that take a long time, the proxy can be generated with async methods (the process of which isn't described well anywhere I have found), but what is seemingly a lot easier is to simply add some 'event' methods to the callback interface, and call them when the long task is finished. This deliberately avoids using Task<> and other "nifty" .NET stuff, but it's also a ton simpler in my eyes. How do 'most' people deal with this? I'm looking for comments in the comments section.

**Concern 3:**

Callbacks are always advised to be written "one way", so they don't try to reply to the server and deadlock. I could write them one way and skip making the server re-entrant, or I could write them not one way and make the server re-entrant. I'm assuming "most" of the time, a callback from the server to the client is not normally returning information back to the server?! Because if so, one-way can't be used anyhow. I haven't seen a lot of examples out there of using callbacks and re-entrant servers... anybody got a link to a good one?

Comment: http://getakka.net/